# Aspectj and catching private or inner methods

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I've configureg AspectJ with Spring and it works fine when "catching" public methods called from out of the class. Now I want do something like this:

```
public class SomeLogic(){

   public boolean someMethod(boolean test){

      if(test){
        return innerA();
      } else {
        return innerB();
      }
   }


   private boolean innerA() {// some logic}
   private boolean innerA() {// some other logic}

}
```

SomeLogic is a SpringBean. The methods innerA() and innerB() could be declared as private or public - the method someMethod() is called from a Struts action. Is it possible to catch with AspectJ the methods innerA() or innerB() called from someMethod() ?

My config (XML based):

```
    <aop:aspect id="innerAAspect" ref="INNER_A">
        <aop:pointcut id="innerAService" expression="execution(* some.package.SomeLogic.innerA(..))"/>
    </aop:aspect>

    <aop:aspect id="innerAAround" ref="INNER_A">
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="innerAService" method="proceed"/>
    </aop:aspect>


    <aop:aspect id="innerBAspect" ref="INNER_B">
        <aop:pointcut id="innerBService" expression="execution(* some.package.SomeLogic.innerB(..))"/>
    </aop:aspect>

    <aop:aspect id="innerBAround" ref="INNER_B">
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="innerBService" method="proceed"/>
    </aop:aspect>
```

Comment: Tell us what you have for your AspectJ expressions. I've never had a problem with public vs private before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is easy to catch private methods with AspectJ.

An example that prints a sentence before all private methods:

```
 @Pointcut("execution(private * *(..))")
 public void anyPrivateMethod() {}

 @Before("anyPrivateMethod()")
 public void beforePrivateMethod(JoinPoint jp) {
     System.out.println("Before a private method...");
 }
```

If you are familiar with Eclipse, I recommend to develop AspectJ with [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) or only install the [AJDT plugin](http://eclipse.org/ajdt/).

More information about Spring AOP capabilities can be found in the Spring reference documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn).

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I think the problem is with the Spring configuration that public methods are "catched", and private or called from inner beans not.

Comment: It is.  Spring AOP uses either proxy objects or CGLIB and none of those alternatives support it. That is why Spring aspects also supports AspectJ.

Comment: So is it possible or not? (Aspectj + Spring + catching private methods)

Comment: Yes it is. But you need to adjust your build process so that there will be a step where AspectJ aspects are woven into the code. AspectJ AOP is not proxy-based in contrast to Spring AOP.