# aspect for internal method call

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a requirement where in I need to place an aspect around an internal method call, by internal I mean

```
class Person{ 
        public void outerMethod()
          {
            internalMethod() 
          } 
          // Need an aspect here !!
          public void internalMethod() 
          {
           }
}
```

I am aware that this is not possible using conventional spring aop, does native aspectj provide a facility for this ? and can I have pointers for the same

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing:

```
// match the call in outerMethod
pointcut callInnerMethod() : call(* Person.internalMethod(..));
```

Or

```
// match innerMethod itself
pointcut executeInnerMethod() : execution(* Person.internalMethod(..));
```

You can combine either of these with `before`, `after` or `around` advices:

```
void before() : callInnerMethod() /* or executeInnerMethod() */ {
    // do something here
}

void around() : callInnerMethod() /* or executeInnerMethod() */{
    // do something here
    proceed();
    // do something else here
}

void after() returning() : callInnerMethod() /* or executeInnerMethod() */{
    // do something here
}
```

Note this is traditional aspectj-Syntax, the one you use in .aj files. You can also use all of these constructs with different Syntax in @AspectJ .java syntax.

Please consult the [AspectJ Quick Reference](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf) or read [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/)

Comment: Won't this work only in pure AspectJ (not Spring AOP)? Aren't internal method calls transparent from Spring AOP perspective because of its proxies based implementation?

Comment: Yes, this is AspectJ only, Spring AOP will only let you work on public methods

Comment: and non-internal like in the question above

Comment: Spring AOP is proxy-based, which by definition makes it impossible to manipulate internal methods. AspectJ changes byte code and hence has no such restrictions

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add an answer to my own question.

The most important thing is this cannot be achieved through spring aop,

It can be achieved by aspectJ , when I tried out loadtime weaving of aspectj it did not seem to provide a solution. (This is not completely researched) ... What i found was that it placed as aspect around the object .. so all calls made through the object invoked the aspect, however internal calls did not invoke the aspect

Only compile time weaving can resolve this.

[the same question is asked here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402009/aspectj-and-catching-private-or-inner-methods)

Thanks
Sudarshan

Comment: Why can't load-time weaving handle this?

Comment: Modified my answer :) , any answer to your comment/question are welcome

Comment: Load-time weaving with Spring should work. If you saw an Aspect 'around the object' that makes me wonder if load-time weaving wasn't functioning for some reason and Spring defaulted to it's normal AOP.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to [this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) and use `execution` or `call` pointcuts and `around` advice. As far as you described your task they perfectly suit your needs.