# Spring AOP is not injecting all the aspects

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm trying to set up Spring AOP to inject some logging methods into my business logic.
But only the first aspect (uiStarted) is executed. All the following ones (e.g. uicreateMovie) are not. The second one targets a similar method in the same class.

LoggingBean

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingBean {
    private final Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingBean.class);

    //This one works
    @Before("execution(* de.rocketscienceengineering.springexampleproject.view.UI.startTheEngines(..))")
    public void uiStarted(JoinPoint joinp) {
    mLogger.info("Spring Log: the program started.");
    }

    //This one does not work
    @Before("execution(* de.rocketscienceengineering.springexampleproject.view.UI.createMovie(..))")
    public void uicreateMovie(JoinPoint joinp) {
    mLogger.info("Spring Log: trying to create movie.");
    }
}
```

LoggingBean
https://github.com/tkupek/SpringExampleProject/blob/master/src/main/java/de/rocketscienceengineering/springexampleproject/util/LoggingBean.java

UI
https://github.com/tkupek/SpringExampleProject/blob/master/src/main/java/de/rocketscienceengineering/springexampleproject/view/UI.java

**-- UPDATE**

I now changed the code and implemented Pointcuts. With this code

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * startTheEngines(..))")
public void startTheEngines() {

@Before("de.rocketscienceengineering.springexampleproject.view.UI.startTheEngines()")
public void uiStarted(JoinPoint joinp) {
    mLogger.error(">>>>>>>> Spring Log: before public methods");
}
```

I get the correct log!

But if I now implement a second method, without touching the first one

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * test(..))")
public void test() {
    startTheEngines();
}

@Pointcut("execution(public * startTheEngines(..))")
public void startTheEngines() {

@Before("de.rocketscienceengineering.springexampleproject.view.UI.startTheEngines()")
public void uiStarted(JoinPoint joinp) {
    mLogger.error(">>>>>>>> Spring Log: before public methods");
}

@Before("de.rocketscienceengineering.springexampleproject.view.UI.test())")
public void uiStartedtest(JoinPoint joinp) {
    mLogger.error("<<<<<<<< Spring Log: second log");
}
```

It just logs the second log and forgets about the first. Why?

Comment: The main difference is visibility of `startTheEngines()` (*public*) and `createMovie()` (*private*). You would have to define createMovie() as public to be able to use AOP this way. See as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402009/aspectj-and-catching-private-or-inner-methods

Comment: That seems about right but even if I change the visibility to public it won't intercept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP creates a proxy for your bean and injects the proxy instead. That implies that it will work only for methods which are called from outside of this bean (because it must be called through that proxy!).

If you need it to work for any method try AspectJ.