# Java design issue where behavior is attached to annotations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, transactions, annotations, jpa-2.0

Let say I use `JPA` by using `@transactions` annotations.

So to have any method run under a transaction I add a `@transaction` annotations and BINGO my method run under a transaction.

To achieve the above we need have a `interface` for the class and the instance is managed by some container.
Also I should always call the method from interface reference so that the proxy object can start the transaction.
So My code will look like:

```
class Bar {
   @Inject
   private FooI foo;
   ...
   void doWork() {
      foo.methodThatRunUnderTx();
   }
}
class FooImpl implements FooI {
   @Override
   @Transaction
   public void methodThatRunUnderTx() {
       // code run with jpa context and transaction open
   }
}
interface FooI {
    void methodThatRunUnderTx();
}
```

**Well and Good**

Now let say `methodThatRunUnderTx` does two logic operations

[1]  call some service(long request/response cycle let say 5 sec) and fetch the results

[2] perform some jpa entity modifications

Now since this method call is long and we don't want to hold the transaction open for long time, so we change the code so that [2] happens in separate tx and  `methodThatRunUnderTx` doesnt run in transaction

So we will remove the `@Transaction` from the `methodThatRunUnderTx` and add another method in class with `@transaction` let say new methods is `methodThatRunUnderTx2`, now to call this method from `methodThatRunUnderTx` we have to inject it into itself and add a method to interface so that the call happen through proxy object.

So now our code will look like:

```
class Bar {
   @Inject
   private FooI foo;
   ...
   void doWork() {
      foo.methodThatRunUnderTx();
   }
}
class FooImpl implements FooI {
   @Inject
   private FooI self;
   @Override
   //@Transaction -- remove transaction from here
   public void methodThatRunUnderTx() {
      ...
     self.methodThatRunUnderTx2();// call through proxy object
   }
   @Override
   @Transaction //add transaction from here
   public void methodThatRunUnderTx2() {
       // code run with jpa context and transaction open
   }
}
interface FooI {
    void methodThatRunUnderTx();
    void methodThatRunUnderTx2();
}
```

**NOW The Problem**

*We have made `methodThatRunUnderTx2()` to be **public** through `interface`.*

*But it is not what we want to expose as our api of `FooI` and not meant to be called from outside..*

Any suggestion to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why modern containers don't require any interface to be implemented - proxies are then created by dynamic subclassing or bytecode instrumentation is used.

So, the solution to your design issue is simple: Implement a helper class containing the transactional method and inject it to the class implementing the interface (and to any other class that can benefit from it).

Answer (score 1):

Following the *Interface Segregation Principle*, separate the two logic operations into two interfaces: a fetcher and a modifier. Inject both into class `Bar`. This allows the two logic implementations to change independently of each other, for example allowing one to be transactional while the other is not. The second interface need not be a public class.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a very valid one on handling the Transaction part. However, if you are trying to hide one functionality over other, you need to consider these :

**OPTION 1 :**

1. Considering - You would need to expose the method that does the whole functionality required by the caller
2. In this case of transaction handling, I would suggest you to keep the transaction open for the time being till it completes

**OPTION 2:**

1. Considering - You would need to efficiently manage transactions
2. Split the interface's methods based on Functionality `IModifyFoo` and `ISelectFoo` that does modify and select respectively and implement the methods and annotate with `@Transactional` on required methods
3. Interfaces are designed to be public that means that you need to be aware of what you need to expose to external world. In this scenario, you are posed to choose Principle over the technical challenge.

I can just think of these options and we are trying to address your technical challenge here that resides on basics of java. Good one to think about.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you call a method on the same bean it'll not be proxied therefore no transaction management will happens, to solve it you can you Bean Managed Transaction where you manually start and stop the transaction:

```
class FooImpl implements FooI {

   @Resource
   private UserTransaction userTransaction;

   @Override
   //@Transaction -- remove transaction from here
   public void methodThatRunUnderTx() {
      ...
     self.methodThatRunUnderTx2();// call through proxy object
   }
   @Override
   //@Transaction -- remove transaction from here too, because now you'll manage the transaction
   public void methodThatRunUnderTx2() {
       userTransaction.start();
       // code run with jpa context and transaction open
       userTransaction.commit(); // Commit or rollback do all the handling, i'm not writing it because its just an example
   }
}
```

That way you are not exposing anything extra to public api, but you'll have a little extra code to manage the transaction.

Comment: we started using annotation based transaction to not manage the userTransaction our self... this defeat the purpose of using annotation based transactions

Comment: Yeah, i know, usually when you face that problem you can solve changing the design of your  classes, but sometimes its necessary to work as you posted, in this cases, your  options is the one  you did or the one  i posted

Answer (score 0):

if you want that methodThatRunUnderTx2 does not become public make it a private method and remove @Override annotation and remove it from interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept that transaction-based annotations won't work on private methods. So you simply cannot hide (make private) a method that is supposed to be a subject of that kind of annotation.

You can get rid of interfaces (i.e. @LocalBean in EJB world), but still, you cannot use private method...

Answer (score 0):

For sure the solution for this problem are acpects. They would allow to get rid of `self.methodThatRunUnderTx2()` method call from the body of `public void methodThatRunUnderTx()`. Most probably the answer for this question could help you: [Aspectj and catching private or inner methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402009/aspectj-and-catching-private-or-inner-methods)

I'm not sure however if aspects are not too big gun for this problem, as they increase complexity and readability of code. I would rather think about changing architecture of your code in such a way, that your problem would not matter.